# How to customize error message (field name) in VeeValidate?

Tags: forms, validation, vue.js, vuejs2

When [VeeValidate](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate/) picks up an invalid field it outputs an error using the fields name, eg.

```
The address_line_1 field is required.
```

Is it possible to use a fields label or some other attribute in the error message, as field names are not always user friendly?

Comment: Why don't you use field names that are user friendly? https://jsfiddle.net/d46tqnhv/

Comment: Because field names match database structure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `data-vv-as` which will show in the error message. [Read more here](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#using-data-vv-as).

```
<input type="text" name="address_line_1" data-vv-as="Address Line 1" />
```

**EDIT:** Updated documentation reference [here](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/localization.html#using-data-vv-as).

Comment: @RohitSharma please check the new URL to the updated documentation.

Comment: The new URL seems to be broken as well :(

Comment: @PROgram52bc there is a new major version since this question was asked and it handles the error messages very differently, so you should migrate to the latest version if possible https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/migration.html#migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0

Comment: In vee-validate v4 there is a `label` prop, replacing `data-vv-as`: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/i18n#custom-labels

Answer (score 7):

For **VeeValidate v3** you can pass `name` attribute for the `ValidationProvider`

```
<ValidationProvider name="first name" rules="required|min:2" v-slot="{ errors }">
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the easy way of vee-validate to customize error messages and names:

1- first install package vee-validate using following command

```
npm install vee-validate --save
```

2- import and register the following in main.js

```
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm';
import { ValidationObserver } from 'vee-validate';
Vue.component('ValidationProvider',ValidationProvider);
Vue.component('ValidationObserver',ValidationObserver);
```

3- Now move to your component and make an input field:

```
 <ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit }">
                            <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(additem)">
                                <ValidationProvider name="Item" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label>Item</label>
                                        <textarea rows="5" id="item" data-vv-as="item1"  class="form-control" v-model="item"></textarea>
                                        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </ValidationProvider>

                                <div class="row mt-3">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" >Save Item</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </ValidationObserver>
```

4- Now import localize where from you are importing ValidationProvider as following
in your vue component in script tag.

```
import {localize} from "vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm";
localize({

    en: {
names:{ Item: "ITEM FEILD", firstname: "First Name"},
        fields: {
            Item: {
                required: "Please enter some title",
                // alpha: "please enter alphabets only"
            }
        }
    }
});
    localize("en");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize your field name to a multi-word string you will run into problems when trying to target this field in another rule. In Vee Validate 3.x you can use `vid` prop to identify every field leaving name prop for the display text in error messages.

Example:

```
<validation-provider rules="required" vid="startDate" name="Start date" v-slot="{ errors }">
```

Then you can use the vid identifier as a target in another validation provider rule.

```
<validation-provider :rules="{greaterThanDate: {startDate: '@startDate'}}" 
name="End date" v-slot="{ errors }" vid="endDate">
```

[Reference](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/components/validation-provider.html#reference)